# Firebase hosting rewrites on localhost?

Tags: apache, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am working on a website locally on (Apache - Xampp) and deploying it on firebase to push changes to my domain. Everything works except the hosting *"re-writes"* on localhost don't follow `firebase.json` (for obvious reasons).

Is there a way I can sync firebase hosting rewrites to a .htaccess file automatically, instead of manually managing two different files. Or any other local server which respects `firebase.json`'s hosting rewrites.

Example rewrites:

```
"rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/",
      "destination": "/homepage.html"
    },
    {
      "source": "/another",
      "destination": "/another-page.html"
    },
]
```

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it myself.

```
firebase serve
```

will create local version of the firebase hosting at `http://localhost:5000`

All the rewrites will work with `localhost:5000`